# WebSockets: How to identify devices connected through same network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Say I want to limitate the amount of connections on a single device to my WebSocket server. For this I can compare the IP addresses, and reject duplicate IP’s (if maximum connections are 1 per device). But if two devices try to connect to my server using the same network IP, the last one will be rejected.

Is there another way to identify one device and reject if exceed max amount of WebSocket connection?

I am using `Node.js` with `websocket/ws` module.

Comment: You can get the `ip` using something like this `ws.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress.split(':').pop().split('.');`

Comment: Actually, the method you suggest might not work if you're running behind a hosting proxy, within docker or in any number of situations where all your connection IP addresses will equal the proxy address... If you use the `remoteAddress` info (which is derived from the HTTP headers), you will only block legitimate connections, since malicious connections will spoof the `remoteAddress` data.

Comment: In other words, this layer of security should be implemented before your application is exposed to the incoming connection, not by the application layer.

Comment: If you really want to control how many connections per client I would suggest a log in as a log in you will have much more control of how many can log into one account. Limiting connections via IP can be avoided using a proxy as *Myst**'s comment explains.

Comment: Apologies, the example in my first comment is how to get the IP and split into octets. If you remove `.split('.');` from the end it should return the full IP and not an array of octets. `ws.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress.split(':').pop();`

Comment: @NewToJS, I already know how to get the IP of an incoming connection, what I want is to check if a client has two or more opened connections in the same device e.g. an user who has two or more tabs in one browser or two browser, both trying to connect to my server; or at least one browser with two or more tabs.

Comment: Checking the (public) IP to control the clients does not work for me, because IP address links to the router or proxy, not a single pc (or any device).

Comment: One browser with multiple tabs open could be detected with a randomly set cookie which would be the same value from both tabs.  If no cookie, set random value.  If cookie, test to see if other connection with same cookie is currently open. In general, I agree with the sentiment here that a user login is probably the best general purpose way to detect the same user logged in more than once.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's easy enough to disable cookies, selectively (for a specific cookie) or as a whole... the cookie approach will only work on the laymen, not against any malicious or stubborn attempt.

Comment: @Myst - There is NO approach that works against a malicious attempt unless you require login before access and you rigorously control how people get new accounts.  I offered a simple idea for what the user included in their question "like two or more tabs in one browser".  Yes, there are all sorts of ways around the cookie check, but I challenge you to come up with ANY approach that there aren't ways around by a malicious hacker other than requiring account login.  So, I suggested a very simple approach that hits one of the simple things the user asked about in their question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I liked your approach, I just thought the OP should aware that it isn't full-proof, hence my comment. I'm sorry if you felt my tone to be offensive, that was not my intention.

Comment: @Myst - OK, no problem.  I added my own answer to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real solution here is to require an account login before getting any meaningful access to your service and to rigorously control how accounts are created and handed out.  Then, you can easily prevent multiple access from the same account by just checking if the account is already and currently logged in.  This approach also allows you to implement rate limiting, service abuse detection and even account banning (either temporal or permanent) when repeated abuse is detected.

IP address is not a meaningful solution because you don't have any way of knowing what the real IP address is of the client when they are behind a proxy or NAT and trying to use the IP address in that case can end up falsely blocking lots of legitimate users because they may all share one common internet IP address even though they all have their own private IP address on their own local network.  Contrary to what Myst wrote, your load balancer layer can't reliably get access to the real client IP address either so this isn't an issue of application layer vs. network layer.  It's an issue where your end of the connection (at all layers) does not necessarily have access to the real client IP address (because of client-side proxies and NAT).

If you just want to erect some obstacles to prevent casual or accidental login from the same browser and there's some reason you don't want to require account login, then you can cookie the browser upon first access and then on subsequent accesses check to see if a browser with that cookie is already connected.  This is not the least bit secure.  It's trivial to defeat (just use a second browser, second computer or disable cookies), but it does prevent users from accidentially doing this and may even keep some non-sophisticated users from doing it on purpose.  But, it is easy to defeat so the cookie protection is, at best, a weak obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this might not be the answer you want, but it the answer you will probably get when all is said and done:

Connection limiting (which is in essences a security related concern) cannot be safely resolved by the application layer. This should be resolved by the proxy (or, sometimes, the load balancer) layer, and even this approach isn't fully reliable (due to limited data and the multitude of intermediaries involved in internet connections).

Consider that the remote IP your application has access to isn't the real IP address.

When collecting the data from the socket layer, the application will either have access to the proxy's IP address, the host layer or some other intermediary... but not the client's actual IP address.

When collecting data from the HTTP layer (as performed by `remoteAddress`) the data collected isn't reliable. It's provided by the client and can be easily tampered with, forged, spoofed, etc'.

Simply put, the application doesn't have enough data to actually implement this security measure.

In other words, this layer of security should be implemented before your application is exposed to the incoming connection, not by the application layer itself.

The solution suggested by @NewToJS is by far the best approach an application can master - limiting access by using a login system, where only registered users can establish a persistent connection and each user has a limit on the number of possible connections (often disconnecting the oldest connection is better than refusing the new connection).

Comment: The load balancer layer can't reliably do this (it doesn't necessarily have access to the real client IP address either) so I don't know how you expect the load balancer layer to do this.

Comment: @jfriend00 this really depends where the load balancer is on the stack and the type of load balancer, but yeah, you've got a point.